# Difference between Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children and X-Men

Tags: marvel, x-men, miss-peregrines-home, ransom-riggs

I've just seen the trailer for *Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children*.
Never having read the book, I can say that it looks a lot like *X-Men*, with its school of "gifted" children and everything.

What I want to know is in what primary ways do the two properties *differ*? Google is no use. All that it turns up is people showing the similarities between the two.

### What are some of the primary differences between *Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children* and *X-Men*?

Comment: The gender of the principal?

Comment: It's like asking the difference between _Magical School Bus_ and _Doctor Who_. The stories are similar but the way of representing them differs in the style. If we can force it a bit, we might even find more stories that sound the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some kinda mild spoilers here:

Funny enough, I watched the trailer and laughingly called it 19th century Xavier's School for Gifted Children.

In all seriousness, we have some key differences, part of which stem from Peregrine's origins. The author was a collected who loved to collect old black and white photos which showed creepy scenes or some form of posed manipulation. If you have ever posed so that it looked like you were touching the tip of a building or something of the sort, you know what I mean. He wrote a book around these photos, many of which were included in the book, with the idea "what if this was real?" So sometimes it's just a photo of kids in creepy Halloween costumes, or a person posing as a mermaid or whatever. So Peregrine's is a place for Freaks. They don't necessarily have powers and such. Mostly they are stuck as children and never grow up. And because of this, they are generally kept safe in a pocket dimension by Ms. Peregrine. There is no explanation for their origins, it's just kind of seen as one of those things that happens rarely, people don't talk about it to the point people rarely believe it exists either- remember that historically, people born with various disabilities were kept locked in their rooms and hidden from the world often enough, or were just quietly hidden away from "polite" company.

Contrast this with Xavier's, where the home is really a combination method to get kids out of a potentially hostile home situation and creepy military recruitment for their own home-grown mercenary company. Here, they mostly look normal, their powers are at worst tragic rather than creepy, and their abilities are pseudo-scientifically based on genetic mutation.

Xavier's is a boarding school looking to teach the children to face a harsh world. Peregrine's is a Home where children are there to be protected and kept safe.